# How to change the sheet tag width in Odoo?

Tags: css, odoo-8, odoo

Is there a way to change the **sheet width** for a specific form in Odoo? I've created a css file to change the sheet tag width but all the form sheet tags width had been changed. I just want to change the width for a certain form. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you have in your mind ? Can you please put your code here ?

Comment: you should apply inline css with the sheet tag, `<sheet style="width:100%">`.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete the sheet node in your view in order to expand the width to the 100%. Just add this function to your model:

```python
from lxml import etree
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = models.Model.fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, context=context, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    if view_type == 'form':
        doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
        for sheet in doc.xpath("//sheet"):
            parent = sheet.getparent()
        for child in sheet:
            parent.append(child)
        parent.remove(sheet)
        res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
    return res
```

That was the answer of [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694804/how-can-i-delete-the-sheet-node-keeping-its-content-intact) 4 weeks ago

And if you have a message box, you may want to use this one to keep the order of the layout

```python
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    """ Remove the sheet node keeping the elements inside """
    res = models.Model.fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, context=context, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    if view_type == 'form':
        doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
        for sheet in doc.xpath("//sheet"):
            for oe_chatter in doc.xpath("//div[@class='oe_chatter']"):
                sheet.append(oe_chatter)
            parent = sheet.getparent()
        for child in sheet:
            parent.append(child)
        parent.remove(sheet)
        res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
    return res
```

### Update

There is also a community module to achieve a similar result [**`web_sheet_full_width`**](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/web_sheet_full_width/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also overwrite how the sheet component is rendered by redefining _renderNode function. You can change the style directly into the HTML component `var $sheet = $('<div style='width:100%'>', {class: 'clearfix position-relative o_form_sheet'})` or assign your custom class defined as an attribute in the XML View  `$sheet.addClass(node.attrs['class']);`. That new class also has to be defined in the CSS code.

```
odoo.define('<your_module>.form_renderer', function (require) {
     "use strict";
     var FormRenderer = require('web.FormRenderer');

     FormRenderer.include({
      _renderNode: function (node) {
        if (node.tag === 'sheet') {
            this.has_sheet = true;
            var $sheet = $('<div>', {class: 'clearfix position-relative o_form_sheet'});
            if(node.attrs['class']){
                $sheet.addClass(node.attrs['class']);
            }
            $sheet.append(node.children.map(this._renderNode.bind(this)));
            return $sheet;
            } else {
                return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            }
         },
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the same result on odoo v8 I have made some changes.

```
@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type=False, toolbar=False,
                    submenu=False):
    context = self._context

    def get_view_id(xid, name):
        try:
            return self.env['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_res_id(xid,
                                                        raise_if_not_found=True)
        except ValueError:
            try:
                return self.env['ir.ui.view'].search([('name', '=', name)], 
                                                     limit=1).id
            except Exception:
                return False    # view not found

    if not view_type:
        view_id = get_view_id('stock_landed_costs.view_stock_landed_cost_tree',
                              'stock.landed.cost.tree')
        view_type = 'tree'
    elif view_type == 'form':
        view_id = get_view_id('stock_landed_costs.view_stock_landed_cost_form', 
                              'stock.landed.cost.form')

    res = super(stock_landed_cost, self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id,
                                                         view_type=view_type,
                                                         toolbar=toolbar,
                                                         submenu=submenu)
    if view_type == 'form':
        doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
        for sheet in doc.xpath("//sheet"):
            for oe_chatter in doc.xpath("//div[@class='oe_chatter']"):
                sheet.append(oe_chatter)
            parent = sheet.getparent()
        for child in sheet:
            parent.append(child)
        parent.remove(sheet)
        res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
    return res
```